# How does median() handle the even number of entries?

Tags: pandas

I have a line of code that grabs a median from my dataframe like this: `median = df[' age'].median()` how does median handle when there is an even number of entries? I have 14,000 entries and I would like to take the two middle entries and average them in the use case that there are an even number of entries. Is this something I can do using pandas? or how does pandas handle this? I tried reading through their docs but it doesn't have a ton on what median() does besides just return the median.

Comment: Why don't you try: `pd.Series(np.arange(10)).median()`.

Comment: Use `pd.Series([4, 6, 8, 10]).quantile(q=0.5, interpolation='nearest')` in case you dont want the mean but an actual value that is in your sample.

Answer (score 1):

The `pandas` `median` will check take the average when there is even number of values

```
pd.Series([1,2,3,4]).median()
2.5
```

Comment: Oddly, when using a DataFrame as input, along with `median(axis=1)` it returns the first value of the two center values and not the average while in your example (on a series), it returns the average between the two center values.